# Rails 4 with Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, polymer

I have started to implement some Polymer components into our Rails app. It works as a charm. Worked as a charm.

With some web components I get this error. It's almost the same error I get for different components, just different file names and row numbers.

**paper-drawer-panel**
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-drawer-panel
`paper-drawer-panel.css:32:48`
`@apply(--paper-drawer-panel-left-drawer-container);`

What could be the reason behind these errors?
[image: error message]

Comment: Cannot reproduce with vanilla Sass.

Comment: Polymer has a runtime shim that supports `@apply()` syntax in advance of the CSS standard. This can conflict with certain pre-processors that do not expect this syntax or use this syntax in their own subsystem. I don't know about Rails4, but it looks like some build system (sass?) is incompatible with Polymer's CSS declarations.

Comment: Oh. Well. This will be a problem. I've seen a lot of other people having this problem.